# Is there a way to define a tag field with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I want something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: String,
    field2: Option<u64>,
    #[serde(tag(value = "tag_value"))]
    tag: ()
}
```

`#[serde(tag(value = "tag_value"))]` is not an actual Serde-provided attribute, it's here just to express an idea. I'm aware that I can do all the serialization by myself, use remote, (`de`)`serialize_with`, etc., but these require a lot of boilerplate code.

The idea is that a tag field must exist, `MyStruct` serialized to JSON should be:

```
{
    "field1": "foo",
    "field2": 42,
    "tag": "tag_value"
}
```

Deserialization must fail if either "tag" field is missing or maps to a  different value from "tag_value".

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean with having a "fake" field? What should that do? Does it apply to serialization, or deserialization, or both? And have you tried creating such boilerplate?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reimplement enumerations. Specifically, you have something like an [internally-tagged enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged).

Comment: @Shepmaster Not exactly. Enums can't be extended from outside of module and it seems hard to me to extract useful error when all possible variants are mixed together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single variant enumeration:

```rust
use serde; // 1.0.104
use serde_json; // 1.0.48

#[derive(Debug, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
enum Tag {
    TagValue,
}

#[derive(Debug, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: String,
    field2: Option<u64>,
    tag: Tag,
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        field1: "foo".to_string(),
        field2: Some(42),
        tag: Tag::TagValue,
    };

    // The tag is included when serializing
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::to_string(&s));

    // Tag is required when deserializing
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>(
            "{\"field1\":\"foo\",\"field2\":42,\"tag\":\"tag_value\"}"
        )
    );
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>("{\"field1\":\"foo\",\"field2\":42}")
    );

    // A bad tag fails
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        serde_json::from_str::<MyStruct>("{\"field1\":\"foo\",\"field2\":42,\"tag\":\"oops\"}")
    );
}
```

This prints

```
Ok("{\"field1\":\"foo\",\"field2\":42,\"tag\":\"tag_value\"}")
Ok(MyStruct { field1: "foo", field2: Some(42), tag: TagValue })
Err(Error("missing field `tag`", line: 1, column: 28))
Err(Error("unknown variant `oops`, expected `tag_value`", line: 1, column: 40))
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cad3ce62a83c344e422d3baab744513b))

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that a single-variant enum takes up no space, so this has no extravagant runtime cost.

Answer (score 4):

For the limited case of just one tag, you can use `#[serde(tag)]` on the struct itself:

```
use serde::Serialize; // 1.0.114
use serde_json; // 1.0.56

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "tag", rename = "tag_value")]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: String,
    field2: Option<u64>,
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        field1: "hello".into(),
        field2: None,
    };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&s).unwrap());
}
```

```js
{"tag":"tag_value","field1":"hello","field2":null}
```